# My Hub class is not calling using signal R

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am using signalR in my application.

This the client side code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var data = $.connection.Hubclass;
        alert(data); // data is undefine
    </script>
```

My hub class is as bellow

```
public class Hubclass :Hub
{
    public void getdata(string msg)
    {
        Clients.All.send(msg);
    }

}
```

I have startup class in Owin as bellow

```
 [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup1))]

    public class Startup1
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();

        }
    }
```

This is the configuration I use in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="Startup1" />
  </appSettings>
```

In the Global.asax class file, I also add this code:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

When I fire up the application, this is the error I get:

> Error CS0619  'SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection)' is
>   obsolete: 'Use IAppBuilder.MapSignalR in an Owin Startup class. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320578 for more details

Comment: You don't need the appsetting and mapHubs method to get started. Try remove that first and try again. You also might update your post and tell us which version of SignalR you are using?

Comment: I am using signal r version 2.2.0. when i remove appsetting and mapHub it give error:                                                                 'hubclass' Hub could not be resolved.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: 'hubclass' Hub could not be resolved

Comment: Try adding the HubName attribute to your HubClass then.

Comment: i have added attributes in my Hubclass but problem is not resolve. its undefine till now.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas without looking further into the problem. If you're starting from scratch, I'd advise you to follow a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

if i remember correctly client proxy is camel-cased (generated or dynamic) so you should use

```
 $.connection.hubclass
```

or add to hub class name attribute

```
[HubName("Hubclass")]
```

and also you don't need set signalr routes by RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs owin middleware will handle routing for you...

EDIT: maybe you can check whether your generated proxy was download correctly by signlar/hubs request, check your network tab at your browser. If doesn't, there can be problem with OWIN intialization, maybe you have to set **namespace** or friendly name at appConfig for proper Startup class detection, check [startup detection](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection)

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="StartupDemo.ProductionStartup" />
```